# How to subtract column value in next row SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i want to subtract values in same column, this subtraction should be done on very next row.

[image: Table Data having 2 columns]

i want to subtract record in row 1 and row 2 and so on
(row2 x - row1 x)

Comment: Is there any order? In other words, is there an attribute specifying an order of rows?

Comment: yes, i have a unique column named as ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ANSI` standard `OLAP` functions as below to get your desired result.

```
SELECT x,
       min(x) over(
                   ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 following AND 1 following) - x AS RESULT
FROM table1;
```

The above query sorts the result by `id` and subtract row `n` from row `n + 1` and displays result along with row `n`

**Sample data along with Result:**

```
x                   RESULT
-----------------------------------
318963.0000000000   -95.9999999990
318867.0000000010   -128.0000000000
318739.0000000010   128.0000000000
318867.0000000010   NULL
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YTUAL9972)**

Comment: Upvote for recommending standards. This works exactly as given also in PostgreSQL ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql):

```
SELECT x
      ,lead(x, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) - x
From myTable;
```

You need to order the rows. In above example I have done this by `ID` but you can use whatever you have.

Answer (score 2):

Here is other dynamic way is to use `CTE` with the help of `row_number` function will assign ranking to each rows.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN FROM <table_name>
),
CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN FROM <table_name>
)
SELECT C1.X - C.X [x] FROM CTE C 
INNER JOIN CTE1 C1 ON C1.RN = C.RN+1
```

**Explanation:** The `CTE` will grab all of your records and apply a row number for each unique entry. Each additional entry will get an incrementing number.

Comment: Warning !! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810627/sql-server-2005-row-number-without-order-by

Answer (score 1):

You need an ID on your table to auto join your table.
Use modulo operator to select half part with alias A an second part with alias B :

```
select
    A.*,
    B.*,
    B.X-A.X as DELTA
from
    theTable A inner theTable B on
        A.ID+1=B.ID
where
    A.ID % 2 = 1
```

EDIT, if you don't have an ID you an `order clause` to determine it :

```
with order_table (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER ()   
            OVER ( order by ??? ) as ID,
        *
    from
        theTable
)
select
    A.*,
    B.*,
    B.X-A.X as DELTA
from
    order_table A inner order_table B on
        A.ID+1=B.ID
where
    A.ID % 2 = 1

replace `???` by your criteria.
```

**WARNING** : Data in a sql table is not ordered. You can't easly preserve the insertion order without a specific columns like ID or Timesstamp...