# How do I create row numbers in Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I would like to create a table using a select statement and add a column with row numbers

So I'd like to write something like:

```
create table schema.table_w_rownumbers as 
select 
    identity(1, 1) as nrum,
    foo.*
from schema.initial_table as foo;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Row number in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952245/select-row-number-in-postgres)

Comment: Do you need row numbers or an identity column? Will you be inserting into table_w_rownumbers in the future and want the values to auto increment?

Comment: @usr - you get this error with similar code ERROR:  Ranking window functions require order by clause.

Comment: @JChao - I won't be inserting. My goal is to test whether two Redshift tables are *EXACTLY* identical as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436540/how-do-i-tell-if-two-tables-in-redshift-are-exactly-identical

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me!

```
create table schema.table_w_rownumbers as 
select 
  row_number() over (partition by 1) as nrum,
  foo.*
from schema.initial_table as foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Make sure you change `order by id` to whatever it needs to be ordered by.

```
Create Table schema.table_w_rownumbers
AS
(
select row_number() over (order by id) as nrum, * schema.initial_table
);
```

Comment: In this case, I don't want to order it by anything. I want the row numbers to correspond to the order that they are returned by the select statement.

Comment: Order is not guaranteed unless specified. So the set returned by the select statement could vary for example if an index was added/deleted/altered. Since you are comparing data what's wrong with ordering both?