# JPA Unknown SqlResultSetMapping

Tags: java, jpa

I have

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "OrderDetailsReportMapping",
        entities = @EntityResult(
                entityClass = OrderDetailsReportDto.class,
                fields = {
                    @FieldResult(name = "orderId", column = "col_0_0_"),
                    @FieldResult(name = "orgId", column = "col_1_0_")
}))
public class OrderDetailsReportMapping {

}
```

and OrderDetailsReportDto.class:

```
public class OrderDetailsReportDto {
    private Long orderId;
    private Long orgId;
}
```

and in my OrderManager.class:

```
StringBuilder queryView = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM order_details_report_view");
        Query dataQuery = em.createNativeQuery(queryView.toString(), "OrderDetailsReportMapping");
```

but I got error:

```
Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [OrderDetailsReportMapping]
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping NativeQuery results into a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188939/mapping-nativequery-results-into-a-pojo)

Comment: See [5.1. Single Entity](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping#1-single-entity). "EntityResult requires us to specify *the entity class*"

Comment: Are `col_0_0_` and `col_1_0_` the names of the *only two columns* in your (database) view?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, I guess, is the usage of `entityClass = OrderDetailsReportDto.class` in the `@SqlResultSetMapping`. From Baeldung's tutorial ["A Guide to SqlResultSetMapping: 5.1 Single Entity"](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping#1-single-entity)

> EntityResult requires us to specify the entity class

You should use the class annotated with `@Entity` to store the result.

**EDIT#1** for example:

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "OrderDetailsReportMapping",
        entities = @EntityResult(
                entityClass = OrderDetailsView.class,
                fields = {
                        @FieldResult(name = "orderId", column = "first_db_view_col_name"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "orgId", column = "second_db_view_col_name")
                }))
@Entity
@Immutable
public class OrderDetailsView {
    @Id
    private Long orderId;

    private Long orgId;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDetailsView{" +
                "orderId=" + orderId +
                ", orgId=" + orgId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```java
 Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
                "select * from order_details_report_view",
                "OrderDetailsReportMapping");
 List<OrderDetailsView> orderDetailsViews = query.getResultList();
```

**EDIT#2**
If `"orderId"` is not unique you can treat the rownumber as the id column: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820897/jpa-entity-without-id), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952245/select-row-number-in-postgres)

Tested on Postgres database:

```java
        fields = {
added >>>               @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "fakeId"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "orderId", column = "first_db_view_col_name"),
                        @FieldResult(name = "orgId", column = "second_db_view_col_name")
        }
```

```java
 em.createNativeQuery(
added >>>       "select row_number() OVER () as \"FakeId\", * "
                + "from order_details_report_view",
                "OrderDetailsReportMapping");
```

Comment: But when I use @Entity, I got this error: No identifier specified for entity: com.mycompany.OrderDetailsReportMapping. Please help. thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the `@Id` of your `@Entity`, see the updated answer