# Sequential numbering of data sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do have the following table:

```
create table test_seq (id int, obs int);
insert into test_seq values (1,1);
insert into test_seq values (2,1);
insert into test_seq values (3,1);
insert into test_seq values (4,0);
insert into test_seq values (5,0);
insert into test_seq values (6,1);
insert into test_seq values (7,1);
insert into test_seq values (8,0);
insert into test_seq values (9,0);
insert into test_seq values (10,1);
insert into test_seq values (11,0);
```

Is there s SQL way, how to create the following output?

```
id   obs    seq_num
 1     1          1
 2     1          1
 3     1          1
 4     0          2
 5     0          2
 6     1          3
 7     1          3
 8     0          4
 9     0          4
10     1          5
11     0          6
```

seq_num is increased by 1 every time when value in column obs is changed compared to the previous row (ordered by id). I can solve this easily in Excel (using simple if formula), but can't figure out this in postgres.

Comment: see similar answer on stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397121/how-to-show-row-numbers-in-postgresql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using analytic functions, something like :

```
select id, obs, sum(cnt) over (order by id) as seq_num
from (
  select id, obs, case when obs <> (lag(obs) over (order by id)) then 1 else 0 end as cnt
  from test_seq
)
order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out:

```
with t as (
    select
        id,
        obs, 
        case when lag(obs,1) over (order by id) <> obs then 1 else 0 end as test 
    from 
        tmp.test_seq
    ) 

select 
    *,
    sum(test) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) + 1
from 
    t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rownumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to do that.

Comment: Please explain how I can use row_number() to do this.