# SQL: how do I select two fields of the same SINGLE row in a group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.6

**I'm using Postgres 9.6.***

I have this:

```
street | first_name | last_name
1st    | james      | bond
1st    | mr         | q 
1st    | ms         | m
2nd    | man        | with_golden_gun
```

I would like to get a list of distinct addresses and the first set of 'first_name' and 'last_name' for each.

my desired output:

```
street | first_name | last_name
1st    | james      | bond
2nd    | man        | with_golden_gun
```

I am grouping by `street`, and trying `MIN(first_name)` and `MIN(last_name)` -- however -- using MIN there are cases for each group of unique street I can get seemingly random **a mix-and-match** `first_name` and `last_name` that may not be of the same row. Obviously, `MIN` (minimum) isn't the right aggregator function here.

my question: how do I enforce that the `first_name` and `last_name` **are from the same row**?

Comment: what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgres

Comment: What is the "first set of 'first_name' and 'last_name' for each"?

Comment: as far as I'm concerned, ANY set where the row is identical for both values. I just don't want mix and match like "james"  + "with_golden_gun" as a set of first_name and last_name

Comment: I think @less was asking about the definition for the ordering - is it alphabetical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function to query a single line per group:

```
SELECT street, first_name, last_name
FROM   (SELECT street, first_name, last_name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY street ORDER BY first_name) AS rn
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the "DISTINCT ON" clause, but this requires sorting, e.g. first_name:

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT ON (street)
 street, first_name, last_name
FROM table
ORDER BY street, first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

-- I am grouping this based on min first_name and getting the last name based on that first name

```
Select street, first_name, 
(select last_name from person o where o.first_name = x.first_name) 
from (Select street, min(first_name) as first_name  
from person v group by street) as x;
```

-- Output

```
street | first_name | last_name
-------------------------------------
1st    | james      | bond
2nd    | man        | with_golden_gun
```

-- If it is okay to combine first name and last name field

```
Select street, min(concat(first_name , ' ' , last_name)) as name
from person group by street
```

-- Output

```
street | name 
----------------------------
1st    | james bond
2nd    | man with_golden_gun
```

Answer (score -1):

As described in [How to show row numbers in PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397121/how-to-show-row-numbers-in-postgresql-query)
you can get a row number. 
Then you can ORDER or WHERE your select statement as desired.

Comment: wasn't my downvote, but guessing that your answer here is best as a comment.  Linking to another answer and saying go look there is my answer is generally bad form.  Answers should stand on their own, links to support.