# Counting rows for a particular name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table temp(name int,count int). It stores:-

```
a|count
1|10
1|8
1|4
1|2
2|10
2|6
2|1
```

I want it's rows to be numbered, corresponding to a given name(also, note that count has to be in decreasing order), i.e, :-

```
a|count|row
1|10   |1
1|8    |2
1|4    |3
1|2    |4
2|10   |1
2|6    |2
2|1    |3
```

I tried [How to show row numbers in PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397121/how-to-show-row-numbers-in-postgresql-query/3397149) this post, but it just seems to number it from 1 to 7 and not name-wise. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() function

```
select a, count, row_number() over(partition by a order by count desc) as rn
from tablename
```

Comment: I'm on SO as well as mathsSE. This is literally the fastest answer I've ever seen. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yesss! It's perfect. I'll accept it after some time (because I can't accept answer that quickly as per SO rules :P )